# Gamecube Resident Evil 2 on Wii, no video, only sound

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, resident-evil-2-1998

I bought a second hand RE2 and on my Wii it doesn't show any video, just sound. I hear the sound of the cursor moving through the menu and I can even start the game and hear the intro, but still I'm stuck with a black screen. I have other GC games that I play on this Wii with no problem. Wii and RE2 are PAL.

A bit uncommon is that I don't have a TV, so play on a monitor connected through Wii2HDMI.

Any chance that the problem is with the setup or it's the game? I would find also weird that only the video part of the game is broken.

Comment: By video you mean movies? Like, not the actual gameplay part? If that's so, does your disc has some scratches? Which aspect ratio of your monitor has?